# How to sort substring in collection?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

How I can sort this by year then by bc?

```
List<String> spzn = new ArrayList<String>;

for(final CcaesItem item : items) { //Items is List<CcaesItem>
    Long bc = item.getBcItem();
    Long year = item.getYear();
    String type = item.getType();
    spzn.add(type + " " + bc + "/" + year);  
}
Collection.sort(spzn);
```

I had idea to use substring, but collection.sort didn't work with substring.

Comment: Sort `items` or `spzn` ? For clarity, please change your variables names, so hard to read your code, is *vec* typoe error for *item* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the `items` collection before creating your custom `Strings`.

```
List<String> spzn = items.stream()
  .sorted(Comparator.comparing(CcaesItem::getYear).thenComparing(CcaesItem::getBcItem))
  .map(vec -> vec.getType() + " " + vec.getBcItem() + "/" + vec.getYear())
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

`Collections.sort` can gets instance of `Comparator` as second argument. In the `Comparator` you can put any code to compare two list's items.

For example will sort `spzn` by `year` and `getBcItem`:

```
    Collections.sort(spzn, new Comparator() {
        @Override
        public int compare(CcaesItem  o1, CcaesItem  o2) {
            if (o1.getYear() > o2.getYear()) {
                return 1;
            } else if (o1.getYear() < o2.getYear()) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                if (o1.getBcItem() > o2.getBcItem()) {
                    return 1;
                } else if (o1.getBcItem() < o2.getBcItem()) {
                    return -1;
                }
            }

            return 0;
        }
    });
```

Also don't forget about null checks in `Comparator` because list can contains null values

Comment: The comparator definition can be simplified by `java.util.Comparator.comparing(CcaesItem::getYear).thenComparing(CcaesItem::getDcItem);`

Answer (score 0):

You can sort your list first:

```
List<String> result = 
     items.stream()
     .sorted(Comparator.comparingLong(CcaesItem:: getYear).thenComparingLong(getBcItem))
     .map(c -> c.getType() + " " + c.getBcItem() + "/" + c.getYear())
     .collect(toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

It is example of student having roll number, name and address. The first is without sort data and second one is with roll number sorting data.

```
ArrayList<Student> ar = new ArrayList<Student>();
ar.add(new Student(111, "bbbb", "london"));
ar.add(new Student(131, "aaaa", "nyc"));
ar.add(new Student(121, "cccc", "jaipur"));

System.out.println("Unsorted");
for (int i=0; i<ar.size(); i++)
    System.out.println(ar.get(i));

Collections.sort(ar, new Sortbyroll());

System.out.println("\nSorted by rollno");
for (int i=0; i<ar.size(); i++)
    System.out.println(ar.get(i));

class Sortbyroll implements Comparator<Student>
{
    // Used for sorting in ascending order of
    // roll number
    public int compare(Student a, Student b)
    {
        return a.rollno - b.rollno;
    }
}
```

Comment: Without any further explanation this looks like an unrelated code dump on the first glance. Please explain **in detail** what is happening.

Comment: it is example of student having roll number, name and address. the first is without sort data and second one is with roll number sorting data.

Comment: Please put the detailed explanation in your answer, not in the comment section.